# empty spaces in form and other issues with my contacts page

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm having some problems with my contact page.
Here are the parts:

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
      <input name="nome" type="text" style="width: 265px;" placeholder="Nome e Cognome">
      <input name="mail" type="email" style="width: 263px;" placeholder="E-mail">
      <textarea name="messaggio" placeholder="Messaggio"></textarea>
      <button type="submit" name="invia" style="margin-left: 0; margin-top: 10px;">Invia</button>
    </form>
```

and..

```
<?php 


$to = "mail"; 


$subject = "Modulo proveniente dal sito www.miosito.it"; 


$body = "Contenuto del modulo:\n\n"; 
$body .= "Nome: " . trim(stripslashes($_POST["nome"])) . "\n"; 
$body .= "Email: " . trim(stripslashes($_POST["mail"])) . "\n"; 
$body .= "Messaggio: " . trim(stripslashes($_POST["messaggio"])) . "\n"; 



$headers = "From: Valle srl <info@vallesrl.com>";
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n"; 



if(@mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
header("Location: http://www.alessandrogiordano.me/test/valle02/sent.php");

} else {

header("Location: http://www.alessandrogiordano.me/test/valle02/nosent.php");

} 

?>
```

First of all.. if I click on the submit button with all blank the email is sent blank.
Even if I make some errors and I get the else message the email is sent.. blank obviously.
I'm going crazy.. I'm making this website for free for a friend but I'm a graphic designer not a web developer. Never again! :D

Help!! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before sending mail you have to validate all the fields whether they are empty or not

Like this

```
if( trim($_POST["nome"]) != "" )
 {
   // send mail

   $isMailSend =   mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
 }
 {
   //show error
 }

 if( $isMailSend ) { 
   header("Location: http://www.alessandrogiordano.me/test/valle02/sent.php");

  } else {

  header("Location: http://www.alessandrogiordano.me/test/valle02/nosent.php");

  }
```

Comment: uh.. it works! thanx a lot. The only problem is that if I write just in the name and click on the button send the email isn't sent but I receive anyways the page from sent.php and not from nosent.php

Answer (score 1):

put this line in your headers

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$headers = "From: Valle srl <info@vallesrl.com>";  
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
```

Should be,

```
$headers = "From: Valle srl <info@vallesrl.com>";  
$headers. = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't use  type="email",there should be type="text"

Comment: Actually, provided they are using a HTML5 supported browser you can use type=email.

Comment: @Bhumi: Yes, you can use `type="email"` - see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html

Comment: All modern browsers support the email input type, at least according to this: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/